# function invoked for each element in array, in time intervals

Tags: javascript

Trying to write a function, that does work for one element in the array - and after time, repeats the same work for the next element (for each element in the array). Array consists of `<span>` elements.

Current function does work for all the elements in  the same time.

```js
const wordIntroGroup = document.getElementsByClassName("word");
const forwardBut = document.getElementById("forward");

forwardBut.addEventListener("click", forward);


function forward() {

  const y = wordIntroGroup;

  for (let i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(y[i]);
    }, 2000)
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span class="word">Naw,</span>
  <span class="word">while</span>
  <span class="word">you're</span>
  <span class="word">here</span>
</p>

<span id="forward" class="material-icons">
  fast_forward
</span>
```

Comment: Please may you also fix the syntax error?

Comment: The for-loop isn't timed; only the console.log is. So it delays a moment before logging, but in the meantime it's already moved on to the next loop iteration. If you want space between your loop iterations, I think you'd need to call a function recursively that starts the next iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for loop runs every call of your `setTimeout` function at the same time. So everything will occur 2000ms after the for loop runs. The simplest solution would be to extend the setTimout duration by that of the current location in the array.

```
setTimeout(function (){
     console.log(y[i]);
}, 2000*i) // multiply your duration by i, the index of your current element in the array
```

Also your syntax error is you didn't close the function `forward` at the end of your script